# custom collection view not scaling last image

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

so I have a custom collectionviewflowlayout that works perfectly but in one of my collection views it is not scaling the image as desired. I have attached some images below, you can see that the last cell is not scaling properly.

[image: Middle of Sequence]

[image: Near the end]

[image: End of index]

I'm not sure why this scaling issue is happening in this cell.

the collectionview is a custom class of collectionviewflowlayout which the snapping of cells to the centre of the screen:

```
class VerticalCollectionViewFlow: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {

        if let cv = self.collectionView {

            let cvBounds = cv.bounds
            let halfHeight = cvBounds.size.height * 0.5
            print(proposedContentOffset.y)
            let proposedContentOffsetCenterY = proposedContentOffset.y + halfHeight

            if let attributesForVisibleCells = self.layoutAttributesForElements(in: cvBounds) {

                var candidateAttributes : UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?
                for attributes in attributesForVisibleCells {

                    // == Skip comparison with non-cell items (headers and footers) == //
                    if attributes.representedElementCategory != UICollectionElementCategory.cell {
                        continue
                    }

                    if (attributes.center.y == 0) || (attributes.center.y > (cv.contentOffset.y + halfHeight) && velocity.y < 0) {
                        continue
                    }

                    // == First time in the loop == //
                    guard let candAttrs = candidateAttributes else {
                        candidateAttributes = attributes
                        continue
                    }

                    let a = attributes.center.y - proposedContentOffsetCenterY
                    let b = candAttrs.center.y - proposedContentOffsetCenterY

                    if fabsf(Float(a)) < fabsf(Float(b)) {
                        candidateAttributes = attributes;
                    }
                }

                // Beautification step , I don't know why it works!
                if(proposedContentOffset.y == -(cv.contentInset.top)) {
                    return proposedContentOffset
                }

                if candidateAttributes != nil {
                    return CGPoint(x: proposedContentOffset.x, y: floor(candidateAttributes!.center.y - halfHeight))
                }
            }
        }

        // fallback
        return super.targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset: proposedContentOffset)
    }


}
```

and the scaling is handled from another class that is called from viewdidload of the main viewcontroller where the delegates of UIcollectionViewController are set.

```
import UIKit

public enum SC_ScaledPattern {
    case horizontalCenter
    case horizontalLeft
    case horizontalRight
    case verticalCenter
    case verticalBottom
    case verticalTop
}

open class ScaledVisibleCellsCollectionView {
    static let sharedInstance = ScaledVisibleCellsCollectionView()

    var maxScale: CGFloat = 1.0
    var minScale: CGFloat = 0.5

    var maxAlpha: CGFloat = 1.0
    var minAlpha: CGFloat = 0.5

    var scaledPattern: SC_ScaledPattern = .verticalCenter
}

extension UICollectionView {

    /**
    Please always set
    */
    public func setScaledDesginParam(scaledPattern pattern: SC_ScaledPattern, maxScale: CGFloat, minScale: CGFloat, maxAlpha: CGFloat, minAlpha: CGFloat) {
        ScaledVisibleCellsCollectionView.sharedInstance.scaledPattern = pattern
        ScaledVisibleCellsCollectionView.sharedInstance.maxScale = maxScale
        ScaledVisibleCellsCollectionView.sharedInstance.minScale = minScale
        ScaledVisibleCellsCollectionView.sharedInstance.maxAlpha = maxAlpha
        ScaledVisibleCellsCollectionView.sharedInstance.minAlpha = minAlpha
    }

    /**
    Please call at any time
    */
    public func scaledVisibleCells() {
        switch ScaledVisibleCellsCollectionView.sharedInstance.scaledPattern {
        case .horizontalCenter, .horizontalLeft, .horizontalRight:
            scaleCellsForHorizontalScroll(visibleCells)
            break
        case .verticalCenter, .verticalTop, .verticalBottom:
            self.scaleCellsForVerticalScroll(visibleCells)
            break
        }
    }
}

extension UICollectionView {

    fileprivate func scaleCellsForHorizontalScroll(_ visibleCells: [UICollectionViewCell]) {

        let scalingAreaWidth = bounds.width / 2
        let maximumScalingAreaWidth = (bounds.width / 2 - scalingAreaWidth) / 2

        for cell in visibleCells  {
            var distanceFromMainPosition: CGFloat = 0

            switch ScaledVisibleCellsCollectionView.sharedInstance.scaledPattern {
            case .horizontalCenter:
                distanceFromMainPosition = horizontalCenter(cell)
                break
            case .horizontalLeft:
                distanceFromMainPosition = abs(cell.frame.midX - contentOffset.x - (cell.bounds.width / 2))
                break
            case .horizontalRight:
                distanceFromMainPosition = abs(bounds.width / 2 - (cell.frame.midX - contentOffset.x) + (cell.bounds.width / 2))
                break
            default:
                return
            }
            let preferredAry = scaleCells(distanceFromMainPosition, maximumScalingArea: maximumScalingAreaWidth, scalingArea: scalingAreaWidth)
            let preferredScale = preferredAry[0]
            let preferredAlpha = preferredAry[1]
            cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: preferredScale, y: preferredScale)
            cell.alpha = preferredAlpha
        }
    }

    fileprivate func scaleCellsForVerticalScroll(_ visibleCells: [UICollectionViewCell]) {

        let scalingAreaHeight = bounds.height / 2
        let maximumScalingAreaHeight = (bounds.height / 2 - scalingAreaHeight) / 2

        for cell in visibleCells {
            var distanceFromMainPosition: CGFloat = 0

            switch ScaledVisibleCellsCollectionView.sharedInstance.scaledPattern {
            case .verticalCenter:
                distanceFromMainPosition = verticalCenter(cell)
                break
            case .verticalBottom:
                distanceFromMainPosition = abs(bounds.height - (cell.frame.midY - contentOffset.y + (cell.bounds.height / 2)))
                break
            case .verticalTop:
                distanceFromMainPosition = abs(cell.frame.midY - contentOffset.y - (cell.bounds.height / 2))
                break
            default:
                return
            }
            let preferredAry = scaleCells(distanceFromMainPosition, maximumScalingArea: maximumScalingAreaHeight, scalingArea: scalingAreaHeight)
            let preferredScale = preferredAry[0]
            let preferredAlpha = preferredAry[1]

            cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: preferredScale, y: preferredScale)
            cell.alpha = preferredAlpha
        }
    }

    fileprivate func scaleCells(_ distanceFromMainPosition: CGFloat, maximumScalingArea: CGFloat, scalingArea: CGFloat) -> [CGFloat] {
        var preferredScale: CGFloat = 0.0
        var preferredAlpha: CGFloat = 0.0

        let maxScale = ScaledVisibleCellsCollectionView.sharedInstance.maxScale
        let minScale = ScaledVisibleCellsCollectionView.sharedInstance.minScale
        let maxAlpha = ScaledVisibleCellsCollectionView.sharedInstance.maxAlpha
        let minAlpha = ScaledVisibleCellsCollectionView.sharedInstance.minAlpha

        if distanceFromMainPosition < maximumScalingArea {
            // cell in maximum-scaling area
            preferredScale = maxScale
            preferredAlpha = maxAlpha

        } else if distanceFromMainPosition < (maximumScalingArea + scalingArea) {
            // cell in scaling area
            let multiplier = abs((distanceFromMainPosition - maximumScalingArea) / scalingArea)
            preferredScale = maxScale - multiplier * (maxScale - minScale)
            preferredAlpha = maxAlpha - multiplier * (maxAlpha - minAlpha)

        } else {
            // cell in minimum-scaling area
            preferredScale = minScale
            preferredAlpha = minAlpha
        }
        return [ preferredScale, preferredAlpha ]
    }
}

extension UICollectionView {

    fileprivate func horizontalCenter(_ cell: UICollectionViewCell)-> CGFloat {
        return abs(bounds.width / 2 - (cell.frame.midX - contentOffset.x))
    }

    fileprivate func verticalCenter(_ cell: UICollectionViewCell)-> CGFloat {
        return abs(bounds.height / 2 - (cell.frame.midY - contentOffset.y))
    }
}
```

I have this working on multi collection views, just this one is producing the scaling error.

below is the extension of the collectionview that is handling the sticky nature of the collection/scrollview

```
extension JourneyViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    //------------------------------------------------------------------ make the scrolling a bit sticky
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        self.collectionViewPart.scaledVisibleCells()
        let offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.x
        let contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.width
        if offsetY > contentHeight - scrollView.frame.size.width {
            self.collectionViewPart.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        startingScrollingOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
    }

    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
        let cellWidth = collectionViewPart.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.width
        let page: CGFloat
        let proposedPage = scrollView.contentOffset.x / cellWidth
        // 10% of next cell to change / 90% of previous cell to change
        let delta: CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.x > startingScrollingOffset.x ? 0.1 : 0.9
        if floor(proposedPage + delta) == floor(proposedPage) {
            page = floor(proposedPage)
        }
        else {
            page = floor(proposedPage + 1)
        }
    }
```

}

hope someone smarter than me can figure this out I've been staring at it for countless hours.

thanks!

Comment: Could it be a cell reuse issue? Maybe try resetting the scale before applying the new scale in `scaleCellsForVerticalScroll` by doing `cell.transform = .identity`

Comment: Did you find any solution?I am having the same issue